# I've got to create sound if you click the button. With my music file

Tags: android

I've got to create sound if you click the button.
With my music file

Comment: Check My Ans Hope this will Help Full

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817554/ive-got-to-create-sound-if-you-click-the-button-with-my-music-file/30817571#30817571

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
 Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
            one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```